# Base Url Change Magento2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, database, base-url

I have changed Base url in Magento 2.1, but it does not works.

While installing I have set base url to `www.domain1.net`. I need to change it to `www.domain2.net`.

What I tried:

1. Update baseurl in `core_config_data`:

   ```
   UPDATE core_config_data
   SET value = 'http://www.domain2.net/' 
   WHERE path IN ('web/secure/base_url', 'web/unsecure/base_url');
   ```
2. Replace `design/head/includes/`

   ```
   UPDATE core_config_data 
   SET value = REPLACE(value, 'http://www.domain1.net/', 'http://www.domain2.net/') 
   WHERE path = 'design/head/includes';
   ```

Then changed Store Url

```
 php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://www.domain2.net/"

 php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://www.domain2.net/"
```

Finally cleared the cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

After serach www.domain2.net it throw server not found.

Reference:

- https://mage2.pro/t/topic/22
- http://blog.netgloo.com/2016/05/13/magento-2-change-base-url-using-the-command-line/

What is it the right way to change Base url in magento 2.1?

Comment: Updated magento changed the name of the CLI command. Per `php bin/magento list` it says: **setup:store-config:set                   Installs the store configuration. Deprecated since 2.2.0. Use config:set instead**

Comment: Did any of the answers below solve your problem? In my case, following your steps worked fine for me. What exactly did you mean by "server not found", was that error displayed within a Magento page? Sounds more likely a browser error page, implying that you had not added www.domain2.net to DNS or your hosts file.

Answer (score 14):

First update both the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` URLs in `core_config_data` to `http://www.domain2.net/` in your database, you can use the above query.

Then, clear the cache by the below command.

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/page_cache
```

Ensure you have updated your **virtual host settings according to the new URL**.

Once you set the applied the virtual host changes, **restart the apache server**.

Now, **browse with the new URL**.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Sukeshinis answer I would also check what domain the magento-cookies are set for. Search in `core_config_data` for `%cookie%` and remove all the rows or replace them with the new domain. Because if you don't change or don't delete these, then it could be that you will be redirected to your old domain. Wasted alot of minutes on that problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to change the web/unsecure/base_link_url also:

```
UPDATE core_config_data
-> SET value = 'http://www.domain2.net/'
-> WHERE path IN ('web/unsecure/base_link_url');
```